# Is the 3.5mm audio jack socket on the Fujitsu Siemens 23 3230T monitor a line in or a line out?

Tags: audio, display, speakers

I have a Fujitsu Siemens 3230T monitor, which offers HDMI input and can play sound, albeit badly, over internal speakers. There is also a 3.5 audio jacket that I thought was to direct the sound from the HDMI signal through to an external sound system.

As I have trouble getting sound to play over the external sound system (not understanding the menu structure), it leads me to suspect that it is not a *line out* but a *line in* audio jacket, so that one could play sound over the monitor's inferior internal speaker from an external source.

I am lacking a 3.5 to 3.5 cable so I cannot test myself to be sure.

Can somebody clear up if the monitor has a line in or a line out?

Comment: Just to expand slightly on ND's answer below, the audio jack is intended for use in conjunction with the VGA input, which does not carry audio. If you want better sound quality over HDMI you need either to redirect the audio to use your sound card instead of HDMI or to route the HDMI through a compliant surround-sound system with HDMI monitor support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **3.5mm audio line in** connector.

Video signal connections: 2 x HDMI (one 1.3 and one HDCP compliant), 1 x D-SUB

Audio:
Audio input 3.5mm stereo jack

Speakers: 2 x 1.5 W(sinus)/2x2W(music)

Answer (score 0):

The 3.5 is used for **line in** only.